# Msys2 and Clang on Windows: iostream file not found

Tags: clang, c++14, iostream, msys2

I followed this tutorial ([here](http://blog.johannesmp.com/2015/09/01/installing-clang-on-windows-pt1/)) to get Clang working on windows. I choose the path to install clang in combination with msys2.

After following all instructions I wrote the simple programme:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
cout<<"Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

After compiling with:
clang++ Helloworld.cpp -o Helloworld.exe -std=c++14

I get the error:

> *Helloworld.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found,
>
> 1 error generated.*

Adding -v in the command line I get:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6E8a.png)

```
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final) 
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin     
"C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-w64-windows-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-    llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name Helloworld.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.9.1" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\\\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\c++\\\\backward" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\\\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\c++\\\\backward" -internal-isystem "include\\c++" -internal-isystem "include\\c++\\x86_64-w64-mingw32" -internal-isystem "include\\c++\\backward" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.9.1\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include" -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\\msys64\\programming" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -femulated-tls -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o "C:\\msys64\\tmp\\Helloworld-2393e7.o" -x c++ Helloworld.cpp

clang -cc1 version 3.9.1 based upon LLVM 3.9.1 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\\x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\\x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include\c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "include\c++\backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\..\lib\clang\3.9.1\include
 C:\msys64\mingw64\include
End of search list.
Helloworld.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How do I get the system to find iostream? I read something about,that you have to point to the mingw headers in clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp. I couldn't find the file InitHeaderSearch.cpp on my computer.

Thank you for your help.

Windows 8
Clang 3.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Due to mistake in the build script some dependencies are missing.

Installing gcc package (`mingw-w64-i686-gcc` for 32 bit and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` for 64 bit) will pull them.

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me

Comment: With `/usr/bin/clang`, the issue persists. Perhaps installing these packages resolves the issue for `/mingw32/bin/clang` and `/mingw64/bin/clang`?