# MSYS2 Clang can't find standard headers

Tags: c++, clang, mingw-w64, msys2

I've installed `msys/clang` using `pacman` and run it (from the `usr/bin` bash terminal) on a simple file which only includes `iostream`:

```
$ clang++ main.cpp -o prog.exe
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I compile with `mingw64/clang` using the MinG64 terminal, it works. When should the `msys/clang` be used in such a case, then, and is there a way of making it work?

`mingw64/clang --version`:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages f5d4dab9b9db65e8b4eff740629c411ea5e21091)
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\MSYS2\mingw64\bin
```

`usr/bin/clang --version`:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages dab5c29f1c61a173e404f1fd78f0c6f56441aa9f)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msys
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Msys2 and Clang on Windows: iostream file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377270/msys2-and-clang-on-windows-iostream-file-not-found)

Comment: @S.M. No, since I already have those installed. `gcc` has no problem compiling even if I run it from `usr/bin`, so I assume all the libraries and headers are there.

Comment: look at the environment variables defined by the MinG64 terminal, and compare with what's defined in the non-working Bash shell.

Comment: Try to Google "msys/clang fatal error: 'iostream' file not found" and follow other answers on Stackoverflow. As I got the main idea, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc should be installed first.

Comment: You probably want `mingw-w64-x86_64-clang`, and not `clang` (aka `msys/clang`). The second one is targeting Cygwin (or rather MSYS2's fork of it), while the first one targets the actual Windows.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The other version works, but I don't know how to effectively include it in my workflow. `/usr/bin` is included in my path variable on Windows, and not `mingw64`, so I have to open the `mingw64` terminal every time instead of using the handy bash terminal.

Comment: Um, then remove `/usr/bin` from path and replace it with `/mingw64/bin`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Then I lose access to all functionality that comes with `/usr/bin`, specifically the Unix programs, package manager, etc...

Comment: *"I have to open the mingw64 terminal ... instead of ... bash"* Hmm, what do you mean by mingw64 terminal? `mingw64.exe` does use bash. It adds both `/mingw64` and `/usr/bin` to PATH. (Or you can do the same thing from any other shell.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's right, but that would mean running `mingw64.exe` which is located in the parent folder (the one containing both `/usr/bin` & `/mingw64`). If I have just the `/mingw64/bin` path, then I lose access to things like `ls`, `bash`, etc, for the benefit of being able to use the correct Clang. Basically, to use all those tools system wide, it looks like I have to have `/usr/bin` in the path?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Add both `/mingw64/bin` AND `/usr/bin` to the path. Or even better, just run `mingw64.exe` (from the gui, with your mouse) that opens a terminal with such path.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've read you're not supposed to do that and don't really remember the reasoning, but frankly that solution seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks.